# Aria-Invalid in an Input Form element becomes true without touching it

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a reactive form in my html code to send a file to the server with a description (required) of this file, but i have a strange behaviour, when i click the input button for uploading the file, the other input becomes red!, if I start bye the description input it works, I checked what changes in the first case and I found that:

```
aria-invalid="false"
```

for my description input changes to:

```
aria-invalid="true"
```

My html component:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="description" type="text" placeholder="age">
      <mat-error *ngIf="!testForm.get('description').valid && testForm.get('description').touched">
        Required
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <input type="file" hidden #fileInput formControlName="documentFile">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">
      Upload your file
      <mat-icon>library_add</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <br>
    <button
     primary
     mat-raised-button
     type="submit"
     [disabled]="!testForm.valid"
     >
      Envoyer
    </button>
  </form>
```

My .ts component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-autre',
 templateUrl: './autre.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./autre.component.css']
})
export class AutreComponent implements OnInit {
  testForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.testForm = new FormGroup({
  'description': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'documentFile': new FormControl(null)
  });
 }
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.testForm);
 }
}
```

If you have an idea why I get that behaviour?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the description field will on focus by default when the page is loaded.

When you click the file upload button, the description field will be out of focus causing the validation to be done for that field.

You can use pristine option for your case,

`<mat-error *ngIf="!testForm.get('description').valid 
     && testForm.get('description').touched 
     && !testForm.get('description').pristine">
        Required
</mat-error>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I can do to avoid that?

Comment: added the snippet for your case

Comment: I added that but i still have the same behaviour?

Comment: check this link, http://plnkr.co/edit/lCRwhj?p=preview about pristine usage, especially name field

Comment: I will check that, but i cannot understatnd why it's so complicated to such a basic thing in Angular :)

Comment: It is not so complicated but just a boolean condition